# How to delete concave edges automatically?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How can I delete every concave edges from this geometry:

[image]

To get this result automatically with only convex edges:

[image]

Comment: if you dissolve the edge is it not what you want?

Comment: The Limited Dissolve by angle will result in a square, it does not detect if it is concave or convex.
Blender generates Convex Hull geometries as collider, so it is capable of detecting that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Convex Hull operator

There is an operator in the Vertices sub menu (under Mesh) called Convex Hull that

> Enclose selected vertice in a convex polygon.

[image]

For the proposed mesh the result could be something like this:

[image]